# Unity/Android ServerAuthCode has no idToken on Backend

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0

I have an unity app and use the google-play-games plugin with google *.aar versions 9.4.0. I lately changed my Backend (Google App Engine) from php to java. My problem is the following: in php the serverauthcode is used to get the users data (in JWT format) - it was working fine. So I changed to a Java servlet and I am failing since 2 days to get a valid idtoken. I am able to recieve the server auth code from my app and a valid token response is made by GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest (see code snippet). Unfortunately it does not contain any idtoken content but a valid auth_token. So I can not get the user id to identifiy the user. When I call tokenResponse.parseIdToken(); it is failing with a NullPointerException.

servlet code (authCode is the serverAuthCode I send from the play-games-plugin inside Unity to my GAE):

```
// (Receive authCode via HTTPS POST)

// Set path to the Web application client_secret_*.json file you downloaded from the
// Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_
// You can also find your Web application client ID and client secret from the
// console and specify them directly when you create the GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
// object.
String CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "/mypath/client_secret.json";

// Exchange auth code for access token
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
    GoogleClientSecrets.load(
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new FileReader(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE));
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
          new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
              new NetHttpTransport(),
              JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
              clientSecrets.getDetails().getTokenUri(),
              clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(),
              clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
              authCode,
              REDIRECT_URI)  // Specify the same redirect URI that you use with your web
                             // app. If you don't have a web version of your app, you can
                             // specify an empty string.
              .execute();

String accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();

// Get profile info from ID token -> HERE IT THROWS AN EXCEPTION.
GoogleIdToken idToken = tokenResponse.parseIdToken();
GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
String userId = payload.getSubject();  // Use this value as a key to identify a user.
String email = payload.getEmail();
boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
String name = (String) payload.get("name");
String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
```

the token response looks like (its invalid now):

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.CjA8A7O96w-vX4OCSPm-GMEPGVIEuRTeOxKy_75z6fbYVSXsdi9Ot3NmxlE-j_t-BI",
"expires_in" : 3596,
 "token_type" : "Bearer"
 }
```

In my PHP GAE I always had a idToken inside this constuct which contained my encrypted data. But it is missing now?! So I asssume I do somthing differently in Java or I made a mistake creating the new OAuth 2.0 Client on the google console.

I checked the accessToken manually via:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.CjA8A7O96w-vX4OCSPm-GMEPGVIEu-RTeOxKy_75z6fbYVSXsdi9Ot3NmxlE-j_t-BI

```
{
"issued_to": "48168146---------.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"audience": "48168146---------.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games_lite",
"expires_in": 879,
"access_type": "offline"
}
```

Is there something I do not see? Help is very much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a root cause discussion inside the unity plugin "play-games-services" on github:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1293
and 
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1309

It seems that google switching their authentication flow. In the given links they are talking about adding the email scope inside the plugin to get the idtoken again. I'll try that in the next days and share my experience.

Here is a good explaination about what happens:
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html

If you do what paulsalameh said here ([Link to Github](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1293)) it will work again:

> paulsalameh: Sure. After you import the unitypackage, download NativeClient.cs and
>   PlayGamesClientConfig.cs from my commits (#1295 & #1296), and replace
>   them in the correct locations.

Afte that "unity play-services-plugin" code update you will be able to add AddOauthScope("email") to PlayGamesClientConfiguration, which allows your server  to get the idtoken with the serverAuthCode again...

Code snippet from Unity:

```
  PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .AddOauthScope("email")
            .AddOauthScope("profile")
            .Build();
```

Now I am back in business:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.Ci8..7kBR-eBdPw1-P7Pe8QUC7e_Zv7qxCHA",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "id_token" : "eyJhbGciOi......I1NiE0v6kqw",
  "refresh_token" : "1/HlSZOo......dQV1y4E",
  "token_type" : "Bearer"
}
```